# Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource' with react-native-video

Tags: react-native, tizen, react-native-video

I am developing an application using **ReNative**. I'm trying to use the **react-native-video** library as a plugin with the command `rnv plugin add`.

When I import the `Video` component from react-native-video I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource' in 'C:\dev\ReNativePlayGround\node_modules\react-native-video'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js 4:47-105
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ ./index.web.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./index.web.js
```

I already took a look at the **node_modules** folder and the files are in place.

I've created a project with the **blank** template provided by `rnv new` command and testing the application with the browser and Tizen emulator.